# iOS how to replace one tabBarController with another ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have Tab Bar Controller:

1. MyProfileViewController
2. Tableview

I do this way:

```
LoginViewController *logInViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

But it covers whole screen, I can't switch tab.
How to place "LoginViewController" in to "MyProfileViewController" ?

Answer (score 0):

Tabbar controller has property - viewControllers. You should determine which view controllers you want to use in tab bar in this property. All other tab bar will does without you.

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
```

Read this article https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/